# SSRS Numbers Removing Decimal and keeping trailing numbers

Tags: ssrs-2008, bids

I have a Report Using SSRS BIDS 2008 R2. I am looking for a method of converting my number by simply removing the decimal. I want to keep the numbers after the decimal just remove the '**.**'

**The Goal:** 
Format a number (currently a currency) into a string but keep the trailing numbers.
i.e. 
Current Value 30.56
Desired Value 3056

I have found numerous ways to remove the decimal but they all end up either rounding my number or removing the numbers after the Decimal point. I was wondering if it was possible to keep the numbers after the decimal place, but have no decimal.

I feel like I am missing something important here and will more than likely feel a little silly once it is pointed out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the number to a string and replace the `.`:

```
=Replace(Fields!MyColumn.Value.ToString, ".", "")
```